# Difference between inheritance and creating new class

Tags: java, object, inheritance

What is the difference between these two:

```
class Machine {
    public int x = 2;
}

class Car {
    public void start(Machine myMachine) {
         myMachine.x = 10;
    }
}
```

And:

```
class Machine {
    public int x = 2;
}

class Car extends Machine {
    public void start() {
        super.x = 10;
    }
}
```

In the first example, I'm creating a new kind of object with the `Car` class, and I can use variable `x` from the `Machine` class.

In the second example I'm inheriting from the `Machine` class to the `Car` class, so I can use variables from `Machine` in `Car`.

But I don't know when should I use first the one instead of the second one, which is better, and so on.

Could someone explain the difference?

Comment: Do you want the car to *be* a machine or to *have* a machine?

Comment: @Joe C I know that in the inheritance case car is machine, and in the composition case car has a machine. But I don't really get what is the difference between those two especially in practical use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example you say "I want `Car` to assign a value of 10 to some **Machine's** (`Car` isn't really connected with that `Machine`, it could be "Gate", "Garage" or other classes that `Car` can cooperate with `Car`, but they are not in the relation "Car is a..." ) variable `x`"

In the second one you say "`Car` **is a machine** and I want it to be able to change value of **it's own** `x` variable to 10". (You could say "I want my car to start **its own** engine, for example).

*I know that in the first example I'm creating kind of new object (am I right?)* - it's not about creating new `Machine` reference by passing it as an argument. You rather say that you want instance of `Car` class to be able to change `x` value of the **one** specific instance of Machine class. Not to all Machines, just to the one you pass as an argument to the `start()` method. Example: `myFerrari.start(gateThree)`
Car has a functionality to open the gate when you want it to, but Car `is not` a Gate.

*But I don't know when should I use first one and when the second one, which is better, and so on.* In the second example you say Car **is a** Machine - so it is able to perform all actions that Machines are able to perform and it also is able to perform some actions specific only to Cars and not to all Machines. To use inheritance you should be sure that you can say Car **is a** Machine.

Comment: From the OP's question, the mechanics of what you can assign as you've explained appear that this is the part that he/she already understands. He/She is asking when to use each one, which is better, and so on. Please make sure you are answering the question.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to improve my answer, thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The first is sometimes called a 'Uses a' relationship, as in 'the car uses a machine', while the second is sometimes called an 'is-a' relationship, as in 'the car is a machine'. This second relationship is called inheritance.. There is a third broad type, the 'has-a' relationship that you've not shown here:

```
class Machine {}
class Car {
    Machine machine;
}
```

The first relationship is a lot easier to understand than the second. Typically we only model the second if we want to substitute one sub-class (Car in your example) with another derived from the same parent (Machine).

Answer (score 0):

Use inheritance when one class needs to be a **type of** some other class because they share some properties. So in this case a Car might be a **type of** Machine and perhaps define or extend variables or functions that are in Machine.

If a class only needed to access or use a Machine object (its variables or functions) it would be better to use your first example. Perhaps if you wanted a MachineManager or MachineList class for example.